# GraphQL and Apollo, how are they different? is it a relationShip same as NodeJS Express, Dart Flutter ...ect

Tags: graphql, apollo

Im learning **GraphQL** and i typically stumble upon **Apollo** being mentioned with it, what is Apollo and how is it related to GraphQL, is the relation same as NodeJS and express, dart and flutter ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

[GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) refers simply to a schema language and Apollo is a way to implement that language. [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/) is an actual tool to use GraphQL.

Kinda like for JS you need an interpreter that actually implements the language features that are defines in the ECMAScript Specification.